# take center of mass or average for matched features

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

I have a application for tracking, then I will have the player object as the following photo shows. I need to do the following:

1- detect features from each frames and match them with the next frame, I use SURF

2- calculate the average point from the feature points which I have estimated from step 1

3- calculate distance between the average point that estimated at step 2, between each two frames.

then I am able to save the location for the matched features,

```
surfPoints.Location
```

but still I don't know what is the best way to get center of mass for these points, or take average for them?

**Also how to filter the miss matched points, I see that there is a function `estimateGeometricTransform` , but this function remove many points from the matched ones !
is there any good approach for that?**

[image]

Comment: Not completely on topic, but having only 3+ points out of Harris is a bit weird ? Have you tried lowering the threshold --for keypoint selection -- a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

So let me sum up :

You have two keypoint arrays, and matching function that gives you indices of matches in both lists ("keypoint 7 in original list is ~ matching keypoint 12 in the second")

So now your question is to evaluate global shift from these local displacements, taking into account outliers ?

In that case (fitting a model given outliers) you should really look into [RANSAC song](http://danielwedge.com/ransac/) (and the eternally funny [RANSAC song](http://danielwedge.com/ransac/))

Although the algorithm works great, it is non-deterministic (as it will involve trying out models based on random samples and evaluating the number of outliers)

---

I'll let you do the reading on RANSAC's theory (simple statistics), now let's see how to use RANSAC in your case :

Your problem is thus : given a list of 2D vectors, find the best 2D vector that minimizes the number of "outliers"

The model fitting step is then just picking a vector out of the list of vector

Outliers are vectors that go "CRAZY WRONG" in direction or norm

Also, [RANSAC explained by Mathworks](http://nl.mathworks.com/discovery/ransac.html)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is that you have non-rigid motion. `estimateGeometricTransform` is great when the motion can be described by an affine or a projective transformation. However, because you are tracking a complex articulated object, like a person, the motion is much more complicated. This is why `estimateGeometericTransform` rejects a lot of matches as outliers.

There are several things you can try. One is to try using `vision.PointTracker` to track the points. It uses the KLT (Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi) algorithm.

Alternatively, if your camera is stationary, you can try using `vision.ForegroundDetector`, which implements background subtraction. It will give you a binary mask showing all moving objects.